# Recreating the brush tool using AS3 code to develop a paint application

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am developing a Paint Application is AS3. What I am trying is to basically mimick the MS Paint. I need to create the brush tool. The brush tool has lot of shapes in it (tip of the brush) like sqaure,circle,rhombus . My idea doing this is to draw circle, sqaure , rhombus or whatever be the shape of the tip of the brush continously using the graphics class on MouseMove. This I know is going to be pretty heavy. Is this anyway this can be done using the bitmap class or any of its methods.

Thanks in Advance

Bobby Francis Joseph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will just draw brush shape on Graphics on each MOUSE_MOVE, you will get discontinous traces on fast mouse movements and soon there will be lot of vector shapes in Graphics, dragging the performance down. It is better to add each stroke into bitmap (and bitmap can be erased unlike vectors). For best results, you need to calculate brush shape extended into direction of stroke - circle would become oval, square become rectangle or hexagon.

For a start, you can quite easily emulate round brush with lines of some thickness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the draw() method of BitmapData to make a paint application:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29

The brush tips can simply be ordinary sprites that you move around with the mouse, possibly distorting with fast mouse movements so that the drawn lines look correct.